# Map item to several items using python's map

Tags: python, dictionary

The following method will transform a list of tuples representing rectangles in 2D space to their corresponding center points :

```
def centers(xywh):
    return map(lambda xywh: [xywh[0]+xywh[2]/2.0,xywh[1]+xywh[3]/2.0], xywh)
```

To challenge myself i wanted to do the same, except I'd map each rectangle to its 4 corners. Something like :

```
def corners(xywh):
    return map(lambda xywh: [[xywh[0],xywh[1]],[xywh[0],xywh[1]+xywh[3]],[xywh[0]+xywh[2],xywh[1]+xywh[3]],[xywh[0]+xywh[2],xywh[1]]]  , xywh)
```

Now the problem is that I am trying to map the rectangles to list of points, rather than a list of a "4 points list"s. how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to reduce the list of 4 points lists to one list of points

```
def corners(xywh):
    t=map(lambda xywh: [[xywh[0],xywh[1]],[xywh[0],xywh[1]+xywh[3]],[xywh[0]+xywh[2],xywh[1]+xywh[3]],[xywh[0]+xywh[2],xywh[1]]]  , xywh)
    return reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, t)
```